# Having trouble checking a variable checkbox with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the following checkboxes:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-2 columns"><input  id="contactTypesCheckbox[12]" name="contactTypesCheckbox[12]" class="contactTypesCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Billing" />&nbsp;Billing</div>
    <div class="large-2 columns"><input  id="contactTypesCheckbox[15]" name="contactTypesCheckbox[15]" class="contactTypesCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Creative" />&nbsp;Creative</div>
... etc ...
</div>
```

Onload, I do some ajax and I pull down json that includes an array of items indicating which checkboxes should be checked.

```
        $.each(data.contactTypes, function(key, contactType) {
            // key is = 15 in my test
            $('#contactTypesCheckbox[key]').prop('checked', true);
        });
```

I would therefore expect contactTypesCheckbox[15] to be checked, but it isn't, with no error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much

Comment: Don't have [] in the IDs. It is only useful in name

Comment: @mplungjan.... it's useful when selecting by id...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are not expanded inside strings in Javascript, you need to concatenate:

```
$('#contactTypesCheckbox\\['+key+'\\]').prop('checked', true);
```

You also need to escape the brackets because otherwise they have special meaning in selector syntax.

See also this question:

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

regarding using special characters like `[]` in ID strings. It's allowed in HTML5, but not HTML4. And because of the above need to escape, it would be best not to use it.

Comment: Actually, isnt it just not working since `[]` mean something in CSS/Jquery? Like `$('#id[name]')` will select an object `#id` with the attribute `name`?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Good catch, I fixed to escape the brackets (yes, I think this works).

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I should have thought about the expansion issue, but I wouldn't have caught the escapes